# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL up to a specific character?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, trim

Say I have a table column that has results like:

```
ABC_blahblahblah
DEFGH_moreblahblahblah
IJKLMNOP_moremoremoremore
```

I would like to be able to write a query that selects this column from said table, but only returns the substring up to the Underscore (_) character. For example:

```
ABC
DEFGH
IJKLMNOP
```

The SUBSTRING function doesn't seem to be up to the task because it is position-based and the position of the underscore varies.

I thought about the TRIM function (the RTRIM function specifically):

```
SELECT RTRIM('listofchars' FROM somecolumn) 
FROM sometable
```

But I'm not sure how I'd get this to work since it only seems to remove a certain list/set of characters and I'm really only after the characters leading up to the Underscore character.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Using a combination of SUBSTR, INSTR, and NVL (for strings without an underscore) will return what you want:

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('ABC_blah', 0, INSTR('ABC_blah', '_')-1), 'ABC_blah') AS output
  FROM DUAL
```

### Result:

```
output
------
ABC
```

### Use:

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(t.column, 0, INSTR(t.column, '_')-1), t.column) AS output
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

### Reference:

- [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114)
- [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651)

### Addendum

If using Oracle10g+, you can use regex via [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303).

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant!  (good to know about REGEXP_SUBSTR, too.) I didn't even think to look for Regex support in Oracle.

Comment: In Oracle you can create functions (standalone or in a package) and use them in a select statement.

Comment: Fails if run against values that do NOT contain the substring you're looking for. `instr` returns 0 if you have `INSTR('ABC/D', '_')`. In the end you have a substring from 0 to (0-1) which is null. Not good.

Comment: @MarcelStör you can do the trick with T.COLUMN || '_' so, there will always be an underscore in your string.

Answer (score 47):

This can be done using *REGEXP_SUBSTR* easily.

Please use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('STRING_EXAMPLE','[^_]+',1,1)
```

where *STRING_EXAMPLE* is your string.

Try:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('STRING_EXAMPLE','[^_]+',1,1) 
from dual
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm upvoting this along the solution chosen by OP since it does a trick. Yet it's worth noting this solution is much slower than the @OMG Ponies's one, especially if used in where conditions. My tests have shown about 6 times slower performing of identical query. This question goes even further on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156391/performance-and-readability-of-regexp-substr-vs-instr-and-substr

Comment: In my testing the ```INSTR``` solution performs pretty much equally as fast as the ```REGEXP``` solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('STRING_EXAMPLE','[^_]+',1,1)  from dual
```

is the right answer, as posted by user1717270

If you use `INSTR`, it will give you the position for a string that assumes it contains "_" in it. What if it doesn't? Well the answer will be 0. Therefore, when you want to print the string, it will print a `NULL`.
Example: If you want to remove the domain from a "host.domain". In some cases you will only have the short name, i.e. "host". Most likely you would like to print "host". Well, with `INSTR` it will give you a `NULL` because it did not find any ".", i.e. it will print from 0 to 0. With `REGEXP_SUBSTR` you will get the right answer in all cases:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HOST.DOMAIN','[^.]+',1,1)  from dual;
```

HOST

and

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('HOST','[^.]+',1,1)  from dual;
```

HOST

Answer (score 7):

You need to get the position of the first underscore (using INSTR) and then get the part of the string from 1st charecter to (pos-1) using substr.

```
  1  select 'ABC_blahblahblah' test_string,
  2         instr('ABC_blahblahblah','_',1,1) position_underscore,
  3         substr('ABC_blahblahblah',1,instr('ABC_blahblahblah','_',1,1)-1) result
  4*   from dual
SQL> /

TEST_STRING      POSITION_UNDERSCORE RES
---------------- ------------------  ---
ABC_blahblahblah                  4  ABC
```

[Instr documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm#SQLRF00651)

[Susbtr Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm#SQLRF06114)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be the use of [REGEXP_SUBSTR.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In case if String position is not fixed then by below Select statement we can get the expected output.

```
Table      Structure
ID         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
CLIENT     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
```

Data-

```
ID    CLIENT      
1001  {"clientId":"con-bjp","clientName":"ABC","providerId":"SBS"}  
1002
```

--

```
{"IdType":"AccountNo","Id":"XXXXXXXX3521","ToPricingId":"XXXXXXXX3521","clientId":"Test-Cust","clientName":"MFX"}
```

Requirement - Search `ClientId` string in `CLIENT` column and return the corresponding value. Like From `"clientId":"con-bjp"  --> con-bjp(Expected output)`

```
select CLIENT,substr(substr(CLIENT,instr(CLIENT,'"clientId":"')+length('"clientId":"')),1,instr(substr(CLIENT,instr(CLIENT,'"clientId":"')+length('"clientId":"')),'"',1 )-1) cut_str from TEST_SC;
```

--

```
CLIENT                                                        cut_str 
-----------------------------------------------------------   ----------
{"clientId":"con-bjp","clientName":"ABC","providerId":"SBS"}    con-bjp
{"IdType":"AccountNo","Id":"XXXXXXXX3521","ToPricingId":"XXXXXXXX3521","clientId":"Test-Cust","clientName":"MFX"}   Test-Cust
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember this if all your Strings in the column do not have an underscore 
(...or else if null value will be the output):

```
SELECT COALESCE
(SUBSTR("STRING_COLUMN" , 0, INSTR("STRING_COLUMN", '_')-1), 
"STRING_COLUMN") 
AS OUTPUT FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

To find any sub-string from large string:

```
string_value:=('This is String,Please search string 'Ple');
```

Then to find the string `'Ple'` from `String_value` we can do as:

```
select substr(string_value,instr(string_value,'Ple'),length('Ple')) from dual;
```

You will find result: `Ple`