# How to convert varchar date into datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, varchar

I have varchar date in this format:

```
03/13/2015 : 2130
```

and i would like to convert it into datetime something like this:

```
2015-03-13 21:30:00.000
```

i have seen example like this but did not work for what i am looking for

```
DECLARE @Date char(8)
set @Date='12312009'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@Date,4)+LEFT(@Date,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work assuming all date times parts are padded with 0's consistently.

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(50);
SET @Input = '03/13/2015 : 2130';
SET @Input = LEFT(@Input, 10) + ' ' + LEFT(RIGHT(@Input, 4), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(@Input, 4), 2);

PRINT @Input;
PRINT CONVERT(DATETIME, @Input);
PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Input), 121);
```

Output:

> 03/13/2015 21:30
>
> Mar 13 2015  9:30PM
>
> 2015-03-13 21:30:00.000

Answer (score 1):

OP wants mmddyy and a plain convert will not work for that:

```
select convert(datetime,'12312009')

Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in 
an out-of-range datetime value
```

so try this:

```
DECLARE @Date char(8)
set @Date='12312009'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@Date,4)+LEFT(@Date,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2))
```

OUTPUT:

---

2009-12-31 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = '03/13/2015 : 2130'

-- Format the date string
SET @Date = LEFT(@Date, 10) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@Date, 14, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Date, 16, 2)

-- convert to date
Select CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date), 121)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56f78/37)

[More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If convert is not working for you then you can use [mid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid) to take date, month, year etc. And then use [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to construct datetime in desired format.

In **oracle** use [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) and this stackoverflow link for taking [substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389571/how-to-select-a-substring-in-oracle-sql-up-to-a-specific-character)

Comment: The OP is using Microsoft SQL Server, so advising to use a MySQL function won't help much...

Comment: @Aludra your answer is right of course. Apparently OP needs a little more guidance on the specific platform though.

Comment: Sorry for missing that point, updated my answer to include oracle related options.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Function:

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

you can try this:

```
CONVERT(datetime,@varCharDate,121)
```

For more see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: The issue is that the input varchar string isn't in a format that convert will recognize.