# Splitting SQL data by specific character

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a value in a (single column) mySQL database which reads similar to this.

```
Entry1,Entry2,Entry3
```

I need to echo them in an unordered list. I had a look possible how can I query the database. Tried following (referencing an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389571/how-to-select-a-substring-in-oracle-sql-up-to-a-specific-character)) but keep getting and SQL error which essentially seems like an issue with the query.

```
 $SQL = "SELECT mytableColumn(SUBSTR(mytableColumn, 0, INSTR(mytableColumn, ',')-1), mytableColumn) AS output
  FROM mytableColumn";
```

Can you help?

Comment: Why don't you just split it in php? `$list = explode(',', $column); foreach ($list as $item) { echo $item, '<br />'; }`?

Comment: Having comma-separated items in a database column is normally an indicator that you actually need a separate table with a list of those items, one per row.

Comment: @MattGibson make sense to have multiple locations for store data. Actually I'm gonna explore it now.

Comment: Appreciate if the down voter can add a comment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Mysql Split a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the query to just `SELECT columnName FROM tableName` and get the result as a string.

You can then use the PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function like:

```
$resultsArray = explode(',', $stringResult);
```

and from there:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($resultsArray as $item): ?>
        <li><?= $item ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```